# How to add new location/place to places api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, foursquare, google-places-api

We are developing iPhone application for nature lovers. We want to add feature in application for user to add location/place if it does not exists as place in Google Places API.

I believe, Google places api does not allow to add new place. I googled and found some other APIs

Facebook Places
Foursquare

I am looking for a good option for API that also allow to add new place. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Adil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [User Place Reports](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions#PlaceReports) section of the Google Places API documentation.